# fire a time after specific date and time in javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to fire an event on specific date and time in javascript. for example ,

if current date and time is 19-11-2015 10:00 AM , and i set a timer on 19-11-2015 10:30 AM then , it should fire after 30 minutes. here set timer date could be after two days also.

my current code is as follows.

```
setTimer :function(hr  , min){


            var d1 = new Date();
            var d2 = new Date();
            console.log("Time 1 "+d1.getTime());

            d2.setMinutes(d1.getMinutes() + min);
            d2.setHours(d1.getHours() + hr);


            console.log("Time 2 "+d2.getTime());
            setTimeout(function(){

                   alert("called"); 


                },d2.getTime());
            alert("Before " + d1.getDate() + " - "+d1.getMonth() + " - "+d1.getFullYear() + "<>"+d1.getHours()+ ":"+d1.getMinutes() 
                    + "\n" +
                "After  " + d2.getDate() + " - "+d2.getMonth() + " - "+d2.getFullYear() + "<>"+d2.getHours()+ ":"+d2.getMinutes() );


        },
```

i called it using `setTimer(0,1);` to fire a timer after one minute but its not getting fired.

Comment: i think it's will be easily your need, http://shawnchin.github.io/jquery-cron/, if you think use jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find out the time remaining using Date function and then pass it on to setTimeout function.No need to keep on checking the time.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var d = new Date("November 19, 2015 17:00:00");
 var d1 = new Date();   
 var timelimit = (d.getTime() - d1.getTime());
    if(timelimit > 0)   {
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(12345);           
        },timelimit);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `setTimeout` is [not a reliable way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097421/what-is-the-reason-javascript-settimeout-is-so-inaccurate) to create timers.

You're much better off using `setInterval` and checking whether you've reached the correct time yet.

```
function setTimer(hours, minutes) {
  var now = Date.now();

  // work out the event time in ms
  var hoursInMs = hours * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      minutesInMs = minutes * 60 * 1000;

  var triggerTime = now + hoursInMs + minutesInMs;

  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var now = Date.now();

    if(now >= triggerTime) {
      alert('timer!');

      // clear the interval to avoid memory leaks
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 0);
}
```

You'll save yourself a lot of bother if you use [`Date.now`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) which returns the date as the number of milliseconds since the epoch. Then you can just treat the problem numerically, rather than messing with the date api.

Comment: Not passing a `delay` to `setInterval` doesn't work for me in Firefox. Works in Chrome, but Firefox I think you'll need to pass 0 explicitly (although that's probably overkill for what the OP wants anyway).

Comment: Yep, just a typo. Fixed now

Comment: You're saying that `setInterval()` should be called with `delay` of 0? That's effectively like polling in a tight loop, no? Seems hardly efficient.

Comment: @jrc It's terribly inefficient, but it guarantees some more accuracy than `setTimeout`. These days I would use `requestAnimationFrame` instead, but if you're building a long running timer, using a low resolution `setTimeout` is probably best.