# javascript: setTimeout() not accurate

Tags: javascript, time

if i use the setTimeout() function in Javascript, the script dont wait the exact time to trigger the code.

here is an example:

```js
setTimeout(function(){ alert(''); }, 15000);
```

Sometimes the alertbox get executed after 13-14 seconds, and sometimes after 16-17 seconds.

why is it so and what can you do about it?

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097421/what-is-the-reason-javascript-settimeout-is-so-inaccurate

Comment: That seems like a very large and unusual offset. Are you sure of your measurements?