# JS Function self-disable for a specific time after execution

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function which is executed by a keypress and disabled for a specific time after execution.

```
function do_something() {
    console.log('lorem ipsum');
}

document.onkeypress = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == '32') {
    do_something();
  }
}
```

Is there any way to disable it for (let's say) 2 seconds after every execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that, is a very simple and straightforward solution:

```js
var firstExecution = 0; // Store the first execution time
var interval = 2000; // 2 seconds

function do_something() {
    // current date
    var date = new Date();
    var milliseconds = date.getTime(); 
    if((milliseconds - firstExecution) > interval){
      firstExecution = milliseconds;
      console.log('lorem ipsum');
    } else {
      console.log('too early');
    }
}

document.onkeypress = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == '32') {
    do_something();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a way: use a *Timeout* to temporally set a boolean to certain value and then check it's value *before* calling `do_something()`.

Example:

```
let cooldown = false;
const RECHARGE_TIME = 2000; //ms

function do_something() {
    console.log('lorem ipsum');
}

document.onkeypress = function(e) {
    if (!cooldown && e.keyCode == '32') {
        do_something();
        startCooldown();
    }
}

function startCooldown() {
    cooldown = true;
    setTimeout (function(){ cooldown = false}, RECHARGE_TIME);
}
```

---

**EDIT:** as *Mosè Raguzzini* noted: Depending on how important accuracy is, maybe this isn't the best method, since (as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53838048/js-function-self-disable-for-a-specific-time-after-execution/53838101?noredirect=1#comment94524830_53838101)) it can be inacurate.

Comment: setTimeout is not accurate and can fire later in the page. If execution is exact time based it is not reliable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097421/what-is-the-reason-javascript-settimeout-is-so-inaccurate

Comment: Just tested it out and it's actually pretty inaccurate, true. Of course, that's not necessarily important, but it's worth noting

Answer (score 0):

A very silly answer would be to sleep javascript execution for a specific time.

```
function sleep(delay) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  while (new Date().getTime() < start + delay);
}
```

Then

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == '32') {
    do_something();
    sleep(2000);
  }
}
```

I said `silly` because it stop your entire script for a specific time, you may not need that behavior!

Comment: This is much worse than `silly`. You are running cpu cycles as fast as you can to do precisely nothing. It will make the entire interface laggy, just to do something that is easy to do in a better way. You should **never** use this code.

Comment: @MarkMeyer so let us know your solution then

Comment: There's no reason for me to post a solution, there are several already posted to this thread.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I believe all of them blocks the entire app for a specific time, actually there is no other way to prevent a function call

Comment: That's not true. setTImeout is queued with an async callback. It doesn't block the thread. That's the whole point of async code in javascript. It's very easy to test.

Comment: setTimeout is not accurate and can fire later in the page. If execution is exact time based it is not reliable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097421/what-is-the-reason-javascript-settimeout-is-so-inaccurate

Comment: There is no need to block the entire app, store the only data you need (last execution) and the rest can be checked in runtime

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like that, execution will be disable for 5s

```js
var lastClicked = 0;
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
  var now = new Date();
  if (now - lastClicked > 5000) { //set a 5s  delay
    lastClicked = now;
    if (e.keyCode == '32') {
      do_something();
    }
  }
}

function do_something() {
  console.log('lorem ipsum');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var timeout = false; //Control variable
var miliseconds = 2000; //Time in miliseconds for the function to enable again

function do_something() {
    if(timeout) return alert("Function disabled");
    console.log('lorem ipsum');
    timeout = true;
    setTimeout(function() { timeout = false }, miliseconds);
}

document.onkeypress = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == '32') {
    do_something();
  }
}
```

Comment: I  believe it should really prevent the do_something function from happening, instead of it returning. Yes, I know it works exactly the same, just conceptually

Comment: I see your point, but this way it doesn't matter where is 'do_something()' called it will respect the timeout that's why

Comment: Hmm, true, I'm not sure if he wants to disable the function or they key event

Comment: notice also setTimeout is not accurate and can fire later in the page. If execution is exact time based it is not reliable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097421/what-is-the-reason-javascript-settimeout-is-so-inaccurate

Answer (score -1):

Lodash has [throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/#throttle) for this purpose.