# React Hooks delay when using setTimeout with Web Worker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout, web-worker, react-hooks

I have an application that calculates multiple differences bewteen 2 points of times troughout the whole day. I use a countdown timer to show the difference bewteen those 2 points. Whenever the countdown reaches 00.00.00 the app will then start with the countdown of the next calculation between 2 points of times.

So I need a countdown timer that is running constantly, even if the tab is inactive. I found out that when the current tab is inactive the setTimeout will have a small delay

This is what I have so far. I have the WebWorker implemented but it seems there is still a delay whenever I switch tabs. I am logging the timer each second so I tested it with opening the console in a separate window and switching tabs.

This is what I have so far

```
import worker    from './worker.js';
import WebWorker from './WebWorker';
const useSetInterval = ({ prayerTime }) => {
    // SET THE STATE OF SECONDS, MINUTES AND HOURS
    const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(60 - Number(moment().format('ss')));
    const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(prayerTime.minutes);
    const [hours, setHours]     = useState(prayerTime.hours);

    useEffect(() => {
        const w = new WebWorker(worker);
        w.postMessage({ seconds, minutes, hours }); 

        w.addEventListener('message', e => {
            const { newSeconds, newMinutes, newHours } = e.data;
            setSeconds((newSeconds < 0) ? 59 : newSeconds);
            if (newSeconds < 0)
            {
                setMinutes((newMinutes < 0) ? 59 : newMinutes);
                if (newMinutes < 0) setHours((newHours < 0) ? "Refresh" : newHours); 
            }
        });     

        return () => w.terminate();
    }, [seconds, minutes, hours]);  

    return { seconds, minutes, hours };
};

// Webworker.js
export default class WebWorker {
    constructor(worker) {
        const code = worker.toString();
        const blob = new Blob(['('+code+')()']);
        return new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    }
}

// worker.js
export default () => {
    self.addEventListener( "message", (e) => {
        if (!e) return;

        const { seconds, minutes, hours } = e.data;

        setTimeout(() => {
            const newSeconds = seconds - 1;
            const newMinutes = (newSeconds < 0) ? minutes - 1 : minutes;
            const newHours   = (newMinutes < 0) ? hours - 1 : hours;

            postMessage({ newSeconds, newMinutes, newHours });
        }, 1000);
    });
};
```

I have the settimeout at 1000ms, which is 1 second, and I've read when the tab is inactive the timer is delayed to 1000ms, but there still is a delay. Anyone can help me in the right direction?

Answer (score -1):

This may be due to the inaccuracy of setTimeout: [What is the reason JavaScript setTimeout is so inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097421/what-is-the-reason-javascript-settimeout-is-so-inaccurate)

When you call setTimeout, the function is added to the Event Table and gets executed after the specified time **and then when the Event Loop is free**.