# Link Gif to Div using javascript timings

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change a background color of a div according to a gif. This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icons/favicon.ico" />
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/iconic/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animate/animate.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animsition/css/animsition.min.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/util.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
</head>

<body onload="resetGif('img3')">

    <div class="container m-t-20 m-l-20px">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-9">
                <h2>Map of KidKits</h2>
                <img src="images/map crossfade.gif" alt="" class="map-gif" id="img3">
            </div>

            <div class="col-3">
                <h2 id="first-bad">Div to change color</h2>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        (function(el, interval) {
            window.setInterval(function() {
                document.getElementById("first-bad").style.backgroundColor = "#2eaa2e"
            }, interval);
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById("first-bad").style.backgroundColor = "orange"
            }, 3410);
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById("first-bad").style.backgroundColor = "#2eaa2e"
            }, 1500);
        })(document.getElementById('first-bad'), 10410);

        function resetGif(id) {
            var img = document.getElementById(id);
            var imageUrl = img.src;
            img.src = "";
            img.src = imageUrl;
        };
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

What is happening here is that I am resetting the gif every time the page loads so that the timings would match. I want to change the background color of the div from green to orange when the dot on the left of the gif exits the box and from orange to green when the dot is back into the box. This would have to loop infinitely for the duration of the gif so that the colors do not miss match after one iteration. How can I do this?

The issues I am facing now is:

- on load there is no bg color for the tile
- The timings are off
- Once the tile changes from green to orange to green for one iteration, it does not repeat.

Here is a link to the gif: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UqejZKWZ_cy9fucaAqcw6pKBoURUYwhb/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

> on load there is no bg color for the tile

You should set the background color after the page loads. Just set it in your `css/main.css` file.

> The timings are off

Well, `setTimeout` is not accurate. Check this answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21097655/11317309

> Once the tile changes from green to orange to green for one iteration, it does not repeat.

That is probably because you use `setTimeout`that is going to execute your code once.

Comment: Is there any practical way you can demonstrate your suggestions?

Comment: @UdoE. [Is this something like you mean?](https://repl.it/@beltekylevi/DroopyStormyApplescript)

Answer (score 0):

You change the code like resetting the counter and put bgcolor in an array

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wrajesh/ht1us87j/13/)

```
let counter = 0;
const bgColorArray = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow'];
setInterval(() => {
    let increaseCounter = ++counter;
    if (increaseCounter === bgColorArray.length) {
         counter = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("first-bad").style.backgroundColor = 
       bgColorArray[increaseCounter]
 }, 1000)
```