# How to use setInterval() and clearInterval() in the same function

Tags: javascript, if-statement, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm trying to create a function that starts and stops a timer. The starting is always on the click of a button, but the stopping can be due to the timer running down or the function being called again from another function.

This is what I have so far. Works perfect for what you see but I cannot figure out how to incorporate clearInterval() so that it stops when the game is won. The functioning calling timerCountdown is located in a different js file. I've read answers to similar questions but they are all seem to be doing it a little differently to where I can't make it work for my case

I do realize that I need to call clearInterval(count) but I don't know how to incorporate this into the function itself.

```
const timerCountdown = () => {                             
  let count = setInterval(() => {
    let timeLeft = timer.innerHTML
    if (timeLeft > 0) {
      timer.innerHTML = timeLeft - 1
    } else {
      gameOverMessage()
    }
  }, 1000) 
}
```

Comment: So `let count` needs to be reachable from the outside. (Also `setInterval` is not accurate) and `timeLeft` is a string, not a number

Comment: can you show us your other function?

Comment: So if `timerCountdown` is called again, then the countdown stops and starts again?

Comment: @epascarello - why is setInterval not accurate? True that timeLeft is a string but it works fine so I didn't see a need to convert it to a number

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097421/what-is-the-reason-javascript-settimeout-is-so-inaccurate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to push the interval id in a global variable. Like that you can use another function to stop the interval when you want.

Like

```js
let intervalId; // define `count` globaly
let timer = document.getElementById('timer')

const timerStop = () => {
  clearInterval(intervalId)
}

const timerRestart = () => {
  timerStop()
  timer.innerHTML = 100;
}

const timerStart = () => {
  timerStop(); // Stop timer by security, e.g. if you call `timerStart()` multiple times
  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    let timeLeft = timer.innerHTML;
    if (+timeLeft > 0) {
      timer.innerHTML = +timeLeft - 1
    } else {
      timerRestart();
      gameOverMessage()
    }
  }, 1000)
}
```

```html
<div id="timer">100</div>

<div>
  <button onclick="timerStart()">Start</button>
  <button onclick="timerStop()">Pause</button>
  <button onclick="timerRestart()">Restart</button>
</div>
```

Comment: IMHO, as let and const are not hoisted, it is better to move timerStop before timeStart

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini Thanks, I add a live demo and I move `timerStop`

Answer (score 2):

`setInterval` makes a best effort to space the running of the callback according to the interval you specify. The thing is: in a game, what you actually want is the current state of the world to be printed to the screen in smooth and timely fashion. This is different to the behavior of `setInterval`, which knows nothing about the screen and is blindly called repeatedly.

For example: if you kick-off `setInterval(foo, 100)` for your game in a browser tab, and then navigate to another tab in your browser, wait ten seconds and then return to your game, your `foo` callback **will be invoked about a hundred times in rapid succession** as the queued callbacks are "drained". It is highly unlikely you want this behavior.

[`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) is a better solution for this, because it is only called when (shortly before) your game is rendered - which is what you want.

In the following code a timer object is created by `createTimer`. The timer has `start`, `stop` and `toggle` methods.

The `start` method records when it was invoked and triggers `requestAnimationFrame`, supplying a callback called `tick`. Every time a tick occurs, we run some logic to see which (if any) callback to invoke.

If the time elapsed is greater than or equal to the `duration` of the timer, then the `onTimeout` callback is invoked and the timer is stopped.

If the time elapsed is smaller than the `duration`, but greater than or equal to the `interval` period, then we update the `lastInterval` and invoke the `onInterval` callback.

Otherwise we simply cue up another tick of the timer.

The `stop` method simply uses the request animation ID to cancel the timer with `cancelAnimationFrame`.

```js
function createTimer() {
    let rafId = null

    function start({duration = 10000, interval = 1000, onInterval, onTimeout, onStop, startTime=performance.now(), lastInterval = startTime}) {
        function tick(now=performance.now()) {
            const elapsed = now - startTime 
            if (elapsed >= duration) {
                cancelAnimationFrame(rafId)
                rafId = null
                return onTimeout()
            }

            if ((now - lastInterval) >= interval) {
                lastInterval = now
                onInterval({
                    duration,
                    elapsed
                })
            }

            rafId = requestAnimationFrame(tick)
        }
        rafId = requestAnimationFrame(tick)
    }

    function stop() {
        cancelAnimationFrame(rafId)
        rafId = null
        return onStop()
    }

    function toggle(...args) {
        rafId ? stop() : start(...args)
    }

    const timer = {
        start,
        stop,
        toggle
    }

    return timer
}

const timer = createTimer()

const onInterval = ({duration, elapsed})=>console.log(`Remaining: ${((duration - elapsed)/1000).toFixed(0)}`)
const onTimeout = ()=>console.log('Timed out.')
const onStop = ()=>console.log('Manually stopped.')

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => timer.toggle({
    onInterval,
    onTimeout,
    onStop
}))
```

```html
<button id="btn">Toggle Timer</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a global variable `intervalId` and clear the interval timer, if won or if no time is avaliable.

```
var intervalId;

const timerCountdown = () => {                             
    intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        let timeLeft = timer.innerHTML
        if (timeLeft > 0) {
            timer.innerHTML = timeLeft - 1
        } else {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            gameOverMessage();
        }
    }, 1000) 
  },
  won = () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      // additional code
  };
```