# Using useRef to focus an element, migrating class to hooks question?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Does anyone knows hows the right approach to pass [callback references](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) using react hooks. I'm trying to convert a modal that is built in a class component, to a hook component, but I'm not sure what's the correct way to do it.

```
  onOpen = () => {
   this.setState({ isOpen: true }, () => {
    // Ref for the button
    this.closeButtonNode.focus();
   });
   this.toggleScrollLock();
  };
```

And this is how I pass the the reference in the code

```
     <ModalContent
      buttonRef={(n) => {
        this.closeButtonNode = n;
      }}
      {// More props...}
    />
```

And the modal content component has the buttonRef like this

```
         <button
          type="button"
          className="close"
          aria-labelledby="close-modal"
          onClick={onClose}
          ref={buttonRef}
        >
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
```

So when the modal pops I was able to get focus in my button close, with hooks, the only way I managed to replicate the behavior is to add an useEffect hook that listen to the isOpen state like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
 if (isOpen) closeButtonNode.current.focus();
}, [isOpen]);

const onOpen = () => {
 setIsOpen(true);
 toggleScrollLock();
};
```

And this is how I pass the prop

```
  const closeButtonNode = useRef(null);
  return (
  <ModalContent
    buttonRef={closeButtonNode}
    {// More props...}
  />
  )
```

And I just use it like a regular ref, without passing a callback function, this works but I wonder why it works that way and why I cannot set the focus on the onOpen function like the class based component.

This is the sandbox if you want to check the full code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/hooks-modal-vs-class-modal-bdjf0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why I cannot set the focus on the `onOpen` function like the class based component

Because when `onOpen` function get called `open` toggle still `false` and it will get updated after the modal is already opened. Please note that [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) doesn't have a second argument (callback) like `setState` in class based component as you have done to set the focus. That why you needed to use `useEffect`.

You can test that by setting a delay using `setTimeout` after you set `open` to true like so:

```js
const onOpen = () => {
  setIsOpen(true);
  setTimeout(() => closeButtonNode.current.focus())
};
```

Although, your approach using `useEffect` would be maybe better option.

[codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hooks-modal-vs-class-modal-vqjmi) example.

Comment: thanks that indeed help but  I was wondering if I'm doing the right approach or there is a better alternative to do it?

Comment: Either way is fine as long your app is not that "heavy" but personally, I'd use `useEffect` as its already meant to handle your app [side effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) plus setTimeout is not always that [reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097421/what-is-the-reason-javascript-settimeout-is-so-inaccurate)