# ReactJS setInterval doesn't re-render in Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code to have a countdown on my site, going from 5 to 0 seconds:

```js
const {useState, useCallback, useEffect} = React;
const Counter = ({isPlaying}) => {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(5);
  const [paused, setPaused] = useState(false);

  const toggle = useCallback(() => {
    setPaused(!paused);
  }, [paused, setPaused]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (isPlaying && seconds > 0 && !paused) {
        setSeconds(seconds => seconds - 1);
        console.log('bla');
      }
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [seconds, isPlaying, paused]);

  return (
    <span className="count-down" id="count-down" onClick={toggle}>
        <span>00</span>
        <span>:</span>
        <span>0<span id="sec-count">{seconds}</span></span>
    </span>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counter isPlaying={true}/>, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

in a functional component.

in Chrome and Firefox this works as expected. It counts down from 5 to 0, and you see the 'bla' in the console 5 times. But in Safari it doesn't re-render. It counts down only once or twice, so showing 3 or 4, after that it stops re-rendering. But the console still shows 'bla' 5 times.

Any idea why in Safari it stops re-rendering, even though the interval clearly still runs?

Comment: What is `isPlaying` ?

Comment: another boolean that comes in from props. it's always true - it's old code that needs some cleanup.

Comment: Ah ok, I made you a runnable code snippet so people can (hopefully) see the issue you're mentioning

Comment: FYI: setTimeout is not accurate

Comment: @DannyHobo I tried running your code in Safari and can't reproduce the issue you're mentioning

Comment: @epascarello what does that mean?

Comment: @NickParsons yeah somehow the code snippet you made works for me in Safari as well. strange.

Comment: @DannyHobo that suggests that the issue is to do with something else in your code or your setup (ie: react version etc). Difficult to tell what exactly that might be though.

Comment: setTimeout 1000 is not exactly 1000 milliseconds and depending on the state of the browser/tab it may be even worse off. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097421/what-is-the-reason-javascript-settimeout-is-so-inaccurate

Comment: @epascarello thanks, good info. but as the console.log does still fire I think that part is at least working as it should, even if it's not exactly 1000 milliseconds

Comment: @NickParsons just updated to latest version of React and still the same issue. obviously there is more in my code than just this but can't exactly upload the whole codebase here, besides it being too big it's also a client project :)