# Synchronize function execution (sorting algorithms)

Tags: javascript, function, sorting, synchronous

I have 4 sorting algorithms which I want to visualize. I want to make them run at the same time. Should I write functions like `bubbleSortStep` instead of just `bubbleSort` to call it every second for example and execute one step. For example like this:

```
setInterval(() => {
  bubbleSortStep()
  insertionSortStep()
  quicksortStep()
}, 1000)
```

Or is it going to work fine if I create the sorting functions the normal way and add an interval to each of them like:

```
bubbleSort() {
  setInterval(() => {
    // sorting...
  }, 1000)
}
```

...same for other three, and call them afterwards.

```
bubblesort()
insertionSort()
quicksort()
```

The idea is coming from YouTube videos like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZuD6iUe3Pc&t=15s) where the colors change all at once.

Comment: Yes, use a single interval only. Btw, if you don't want to write functions that only do one step at a time, use generator functions where you can `yield` from the middle of control structures.

Answer (score 2):

JS timer functions [are not all that precise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097421/what-is-the-reason-javascript-settimeout-is-so-inaccurate). If each different algorithm initializes a different timer, it might be an issue; they might get out of sync. (If you were using recursive `setTimeout`s, I know they'd *definitely* eventually get out of sync if the process took a long time.) Setting just a single timer and running one step for each algorithm inside that timer is probably a more trustworthy approach.

Note that the syntax you'll need will be something like

```
setInterval(() => {
  bubbleSortStep()
  insertionSortStep()
  quicksortStep()
}, 1000)
```

(`setInterval` accepts a function, not an object)

Comment: Yeah, it was more like pseudocode, but I will change that to be right. Thank you! That was my thought too, about getting out of sync. I will try your recommenced approach. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Thanks! I implemented my idea and it works fine with the approach you recommended.